Creating a new column containing time in months based on specific conditions
I am trying to prepare an Excel file for analysis, but I can't seem to figure out how to solve the issue below.
The data involves a study in which participatns are followed for 5 years (even though longer follow-up is available). During these 5 years, it is recorded whether a specific event happens or not.
I have the following data available (an example):



ID
Entry date
Event




1
13-02-2020
27-06-2023


2
06-07-2021



3
12-01-2020
13-10-2022


4
09-08-2020
26-02-2027


5
17-05-2021




"Entry date" is time of entry to the study, and "Event" is the date of the event, if the event happened. If there is a blank cell, it means the event did not happen.
I am now trying to create a new column called "Time", which contains the time in months from the "Entry date" to the date of the "Event", if the event happened within 5 years; or, if the event did not happen at all or happened after 5 years, the time in months which would equal the entry date + 5 years (thus indicating that the participant was followed for 5 years and then censored).
I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Depending on your definition of a "month", perhaps:
=IFERROR(MIN(DATEDIF(B2,C2,"m"),60),60)


If you do not need an absolutely exact "month", then use e.g.
=ROUND( (C2-B2) / (365.25/12) ,0)
There is an average of 365.25 days in a year, and 12 months in the same year.
